# Is a MutationObserver destroyed when the observed node is destroyed?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I observe a node by simply doing

```
new MutationObserver(callback)
  .observe(shape.node, {attributes: true})
```

As you can see I dont have any references to the observer. The observed node will get destroyed at some point.

Is the memory for the node and for the observer cleaned up? Or do they keep themselves alife? And if so: How can I prevent that from happening? I do not know when the node gets removed.

Ofc I could also observe the parent and disconnect the first observer when the parent has a "child list changed" observed but I would like to avoid that

Comment: MDN says [it will be GC'd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: @wOxxOm I read through it mutiple times now but it seems I am blind - cant find it :/

Comment: I gave the wrong link, should've been to [MO#disconnect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/disconnect).

Comment: Ah, there it is! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`MutationObserver`s hold a weak reference to the nodes they are observing, and the nodes have a strong reference to the mutation observer. That means that in your case, the only thing referencing the observer is the node object. If the node is GCed, nothing will be referencing the observer so it will also be GCed.

See [DOM Specification section 4.3.4. Garbage collection](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#garbage-collection), which states:

> Nodes have a strong reference to registered observers in their registered observer list.
>
> Registered observers in a node’s registered observer list have a weak reference to the node.

Comment: Thanks. Where is that documented? I've searched MDN but all I could find was [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/disconnect#usage_notes) related point. I'm not diagreeing, I just want to know if this is documented and thus guaranteed behaviour?

Comment: @lonix Good call, edited my answer